# Swing, serial port and JSF

Tags: java, swing, jsf, serial-port

I just need and idea to resolve this situation: We made a Swing application to capture data over a serial port, this capture fires some alarms (rendered in a JPane) and at the same time this info is stored in a database to supply some statisticals (using JFreechart and JasperReports). Now, we want to present the same information in a web base interface and we are thinking in a JSF + Primefaces over Apache Tomcat 7 application.

The statisticals it´s not a problem, our concern is how to notify the web application that an event is fire in the serial port to show the same alarm that the captures made by Swing app is showed in the client's browser?. The final user wants to mantain both formats: a local view (Swing) and the web view for manager purposes.

Are our propose the correct one (Swing -> JSF + Primefaces)?, Are there any other alternatives?

Thanks in advances for any idea

Comment: Seems reasonable - Primefaces have [comet support](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) which I guess will be crucial as the server needs to inform the clinets about asynchronous events.

Comment: Ok, but how can I send that asyncronous events to the web application?

Comment: Well that depends on the volume of those events. One possibility is to create a web service hosted on your server, which the swing appliaction could call to inform about the event. Another possibility would be to run the port monitoring logic on a separate thread of the webserver.

Comment: Thanks a lot, we'll test both solutions to see which is better, in other words faster and easier to implement and run.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to resolve the problem. I left here the solution that I found it, first: 
1. To test the solution I used Glassfish 3.1.2.2 instead of Tomcat 7, Netbeans 7.3 and PrimeFaces 3.5
2. I made a sample application based on this [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/flower_overview.html).
3. I implemented the PimePush Counter example of PrimeFaces demo page.
4. I made a Swing application, with a button to simulated the action of the serial port capture, this app use the ws to push content in the web application.
5. The GF has comet and Web sockets support enabled.

But there's a problem, every time I restart the Glassfish, it´s necessary to undeploy the application and them redeploy again in order that web service will be avalaible. Why this?, I missing somethig?

Here the code:

the ws class:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "BotonService")
@Stateless
public class BotonService {

    private boolean push = false;

    @EJB
    private ServiceShare servicio;

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "setPush")
    public void setPush(@WebParam(name = "push") boolean push) {
        this.push = push;
        servicio.setPush(push);
        servicio.firePush();
    }

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getPush")
    public Boolean getPush() {
        return this.push;
    }  
}
```

Here the ManagedBean class:

```
@Stateless
@ManagedBean(name = "globalCounter")
@ApplicationScoped
public class GlobalCounterBean implements Serializable {

    private int count;
    private String CHANNEL = "/counter";

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public synchronized void increment() {
        count++;
        PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
        pushContext.push(CHANNEL, String.valueOf(count));
    }
}
```

And here an EJB used to communicate the WS with the Managedbean:

```
@Stateless
public class ServiceShare {

    @EJB
    private GlobalCounterBean counter;

    private boolean push = false;

    public boolean getPush() {
        return push;
    }

    public void setPush(boolean push){
        this.push = push;
    }

    public void firePush(){
        if(this.push){
            counter.increment();
        }
    }
 }
```

The JSF page is exactly the same that in the PrimeFaces demo.

Every time I push the button in the swing application that I made it, the counter is updated in each machine that is connected, that´s the idea of the final application. But again, why I have to redeploy the web application in order that the ws-client in the swing application could find it?. Is there any configuration that I'm missing in the GF server to avoid that behaviour?